# Why does the webmatrix not work for me?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webmatrix

Error

```
There was an error creating site 'Empty Site1'.

Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070585): Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostElement.GetPropertyByName(String bstrSubName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_SslFlags()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_CertificateHash()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(String bindingInformation, String bindingProtocol)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteCollection.Add(String name, String bindingProtocol, String bindingInformation, String physicalPath, Byte[] certificateHash, String certificateStore, SslFlags sslFlags)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.CreateSiteHelper.CreateSite(String name, String path, FrameworkType frameworkType)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.CreateSiteHelper.CreateSiteFromName(String name, Boolean makeNameUnique)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Gallery.Server.GalleryModuleService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<AddSiteFromName>b__f(ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.Server.ModuleService.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<InvokeOnMTA>b__0()
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.TaskServiceImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<InvokeOnMTA>b__5()
```

---

I am trying to create an empty website from template using webmatrix2 but I am always reported the above error. And here is the template install log error

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'EmptySite' to the cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\EmptySite\ce7d29f43ac4cb3be29181feba3458cb66fbf60f\EmptySite.zip instead of downloading from http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/3/8/33841B52-1126-4892-AEBA-DD67EFE5CBFA/EmptySite.zip
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9808264
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9808264 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 06:12:11 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=cf753bfbb7a34e4e85e1644c1f94456c&HASH=fb3b&LV=20128&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 06:13:10 GMT


DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Sharepoint
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Office
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID SQL
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID SQL
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID WIF
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID identity
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID federation
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID claims
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID authentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Katalready
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9806977
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9806977 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 06:12:12 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/2.0/templatefeed.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=f116c112acb5d74b9ddfc72cac17bf37&HASH=12c1&LV=20128&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 05 Aug 2012 06:13:12 GMT


DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID HTML
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID HTML
```

Could someone be nice to explain me what the cause is ? Thank you.

Comment: if exist clear this directory and again try ` C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\EmptySite\ce7d29f43ac4cb3be29181feba3458cb66fbf60f\EmptySite.zip`

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't work at all. It reports the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would uninstall WebMatrix and IIS7.5 and reinstall clean versions.  I had a similar problem when I installed WebMatrix 2 and a clean install worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on the other thread - have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS Express?